# SendGrid: getting precise stats with the API

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am having some trouble (and also don´t now if it's possible) getting the data via the API that has to do with opens, clicks, etc. but with more precision. With this I mean being able to get who opened the emails, who clicked on them, where they clicked, etc. Is this possible? If so, any example calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can't retrive that information via the historical stats API.  We actually aggregate all the individual events (clicks, opens, etc.) and disregard the extra informations.  It's designed to be used in reporting really.

On the other hand, you could use the [events webhook](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API%20Reference/Webhooks/event.html) to get the data that you're looking for in real time.  There's no way to do historical queries on that, but as events are passing through our system, you'll get POSTs like this:

```
{"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000095,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"delivered"}
{"email":"foo@bar.com","timestamp":1322000096,"unique_arg":"my unique arg","event":"open"}
```

There is a PHP example in the docs too.

Comment: Do you know if there is any other solution that has this historical reporting for events?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but you could easily just dump the SendGrid event log into a database that gives you a RESTful interface to query on (mongo, elastic search, etc).